# ERROR in node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/logger/logger.d.ts(46,5)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am using "@angular/*": "6.0.0-beta.1",

With or without the following installed... and with either versions

```
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer ^0.4.0 or ^0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core ^0.4.0 or ^0.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics ^0.4.0 or ^0.3.1
```

... I am receiving the following errors

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/logger/logger.d.ts(46,5): error TS2416: Property 'debug' in type 'Log
ger' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Observable<LogEntry>'.
  Type '(message: string, metadata?: JsonObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(...any: any[]) => Observable<L
ogEntry>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LogEntry>'.
node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/logger/logger.d.ts(46,5): error TS2425: Class 'Observable<LogEntry>' defines i
nstance member property 'debug', but extended class 'Logger' defines it as instance member function.
```

About 3 hours prior I did recent installation of the devkit 0.4.0 versions. Everything seem alright but then the error started.

I remove all devkit packages, do a 'yarn' with and without the devkits, but the error persist.

Although there is no devkit in my package.json, node_modules has the 0.3.1 version

The app does not compile

Comment: You go for the the beta versions and asking for help... maybe don't go beta?

Comment: Wise comment. Only everthing was working well. I will downgrade. Thanks.

Comment: The error still persist with @angular/*: "5.2.5 even after cleaning node_modules performing yarn install